# Safari browser Javascript array seems to sort strings incorrectly

Tags: javascript, safari

In the Safari console:

```
var x = ["20", "21"]; x.sort(function(a,b){return b > a}); x
> ["20", "21"]
```

Chrome:

```
var x = ["20", "21"]; x.sort(function(a,b){return b > a}); x
> ["21", "20"]
```

This works as expected in Safari, though (matches Chrome):

```
"20" > "21"
false
```

Scratching my head.

Comment: And you have of course tried the more appropriate way of sorting strings with [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and doing `return a.localeCompare(b);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison callback function must return a number instead of just true/false. This is very different from in other languages where you can just provide a "less than" function for the purpose of comparison in sorting.

The differing implementations of the `sort()` in these two browsers results in the differing observed results...

The body of the sort function should just be `return b - a`.

Comment: not entirely accurate , return negative ,0, or positive.

Comment: @charlietfl I've undeleted the answer and corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) need a callback for the type you want to sort.

Basically you need to use number for sorting, because string sorts strings and not numerical. The first sorts by string and the second by numerical values.

```js
var x = ["20", "21", "2", "100", "10", "1", "3", "30"];

x.sort();
console.log(x);

x.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b; // implicit casting to Number
});
console.log(x);
```

Comment: This is not the core problem, the core problem was the improper comparison callback provided to sort. I wrote an answer but deleted it, I should have edited it to be more correct instead

Comment: This happens to work in this specific case, but users should be warned against using this for general string comparisons, as strings such as 'foo' can't be "cast" to numbers correctly and will result with NaN.